# getDay() function of "date-fns" gives different results for the same date

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, date-fns

Given the following 2 dates in ISO format:

```
2022-08-28T01:00:00.000Z
```

```
2022-08-28T23:00:00.000Z
```

`getDay()` returns `0` for the first one, and `1` for the second one.

Note that it's the same date, and only time is changed.

I am assuming it returns the result after converting it to local time. Because of that behavior, my logic has some side-effects.

Is there a way to get the result without conversion to local time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getDay` documentation clearly states it returns results in local time.  You need the `getUTCDay` function.

Comment: Hi, I checked docs: https://date-fns.org/v2.29.2/docs/getDay. I don't see it states it returns the result in local time. Where is that statement? Also, `getUTCDay` does not exist in `date-fns`. Are you suggesting native Date function?

Comment: First sentence here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: But this is native function. I am using `date-fns` library because I am doing some other more complex stuff in addition. The question was related to `getDay()` of the `date-fns` library. :D

Comment: Are you clear that `x = getDay(new Date(2012, 1, 29))` is exactly the same as `d  = new Date(2012, 1, 29)` / `x = d.getDay()`?  That's a very, very thin wrapper around the native `Date` type.